# find a bijection to prove each of the following statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a bijection to prove each of the following statements. Yes, you need to justify that the function you have is a bijection. 
(a) |E| = |O| where E = {2k : k ∈Z} and O = {2k + 1 : k ∈Z} 
(b) |(0,1)| = |(1,5)| 
(c) The set S =n√2 n : n ∈Nois denumerable.
(d) Z×{0,1} is denumerable.

Do I actually have to find a function to represent each statement, or can I justify why the statement itself is a bijection?  For example, for (a), is it sufficient to say that (f o g): E => O is bijective by showing that f and g are bijective.  Or do I have to actually find (f o g)= _____________?

Thanks for any clarification!!

Comment: Perhaps you may need to make your question more clearer, I dont actually see what are $f$ and $g$

Comment: To show that two sets are equipotent, you do indeed need to construct a well defined function between the two sets, and show that it is bijective. For instance in (a) you may define a function $f:E \to O$ such that $f: 2k \mapsto 2k+1$ for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. This is trivially bijective and hence allows you to conclude that $|E|=|O|$.